# How to get the data inside `ContentPresenter` in code behind WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, contentpresenter

is there a way to get the `content` inside the `ContentPresenter` in code behind ?

I have this code in my code behind

```
  ContentPresenter templateParent = GetFrameworkElementByName<ContentPresenter>(listViewItem);
```

and inside my `templateParent` have the content as shown below

I want to do something like

```
String itemName = (ItemName in my templateParent);
```

how can I do that ? Is it possible to do that ?

Comment: Google viewmodel first. Work with data you bind to the content property of a contentcontrol rather than UI controls. Datatemplate your data into UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume Item is the class name for your listviewItem,then you can cast contenetpresenter's content as follows

```
String itemName = ((Item)templateParent.Content).ItemName.toString();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It's working fine :)